# How do I patch specific files with one git command?

Tags: git, command-line, version-control, patch

I have two branches, A and B.

Let's say branch A has files A1, A2, F1 and F2.

Branch B has files B1, B2, F1 and F2.

In this case, they share the same files F1 and F2, which are crucial for each branch. A1, A2/B1, B2 are independent to each branch, and remain different to one another.

Since the branches are still under development, I would usually work on Branch A, make changes to files F1 and F2, and do the following command to update only the files F1 and F2 on Branch B (once all commits are made):

```
git checkout B
git checkout --patch A F1
# ... (i'll review and choose the changes to be made here)
git checkout --patch A F2
# ... (same here)
```

However, what if I have, say 10 files to be patched each time? This would be a tedious process - my method right now relies on having to call this command as many times as the number of files I wish to patch. Is there a work-around for this (i.e. patching all these files at once with a single command?).

Thank you.

Comment: well... `--patch` is _asking_ for interactive operation. Is it a problem _not_ to use it? `git checkout A F1; git checkout A F2`? Or `git checkout A F1 F2` (perhaps with a `--` between `A` and `F1` :thinking:)

Comment: @eftshift0 well there are some mini changes that are specific to each branch, but the majority of the changes in F1 and F2 should be the same, hence I have to still rely on the --patch. But in any case even if I don't have to use it, its still a pain to have to call the command numerous times for numerous files

Comment: ok.... how about setting up a script? Or even a git alias? or a bash alias?

Comment: mm i did think of setting up a git/bash alias, but that seems to be a pretty temporary solution - but i guess that would work for now. I was wondering if there was a more proper way that such problems are approached, or does everyone just do it manually just like how i outlined above.

Comment: Perhaps with a little more thinking you can get the branching workflow in better (or different, at least?) shape so you can do the merges (or others) that people normally do instead of having to use checkouts the way you do?

Comment: If I were in your shoes, I (think I) would either 1.) Make a third branch `F`, and only edit the F files on that branch, and keep rebasing my `A` and `B` onto the `F` branch anytime it changes. Or 2.) If it's just me working on both A and B I'd do it all on one branch and make sure I make separate commits for A only and B only, and then when I'm all done I'd make separate branches at the end with some interactive rebases if I needed separate PRs, or I'd just do a single PR for both if I didn't.

Comment: This has no direct effect on your question, but note that in Git, *branches* don't contain files: it's *commits* that contain files (and then branches contain commits, with some commits being on multiple branches simultaneously).

Comment: In any case, see @TTT's comment, and consider having a branch where you work on just the "F" files. You could then merge that branch *into* both other branches now and then. The tip commit on the branch that contains the "F" files can have any versions of the other files that you like; as long as commits you make *on* the `F` branch don't touch any of those files, the merge won't have any work on those other files to combine, and hence won't affect them.